# Bootstrap Pull and Push to fix layout order

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Right now I have the following:

**EDIT** I didn't think it was necessary to include E, but apparently it is.

```
  <div class='row'>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      A
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      B
      D
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='row'>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      C
      E
    </div>
  </div>
```

to achieve the following layout on Desktop (on the left):

[image]
I am trying to achieve this look on mobile (on the right).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
<div class="container">    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">A</div>
                <div class="col-md-12">C</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">B</div>
                <div class="col-md-12">D</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

No need to push pull. [Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27353/)

For your updated question:

```
<div class="container">    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">A</div>
                <div class="col-md-12">C</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">B</div>
                <div class="col-md-12">D</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            E
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @Sven thanks for the answer. But I forgot to mention an additional element 'E' which might affect your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2dukj82v/3/)

```html
<div class='row'>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                A
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                C
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                B
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                D
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is almost the same as my answer, tip you can remove  col-lg and col -md cause you already have col-sm with the same value, also col-xs-12 would be default if you only have col-sm-8

Comment: Yes, we post the answer almost at the same time. The existing col-lg-8, col-md-8 and col-sm-8 pretends to be an example for Sparrowcide in order to show him what he can do with boostrap. He can modify or remove what he does not need.